# Matrix sort parameter + Zoo Visitor not working as expected

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, zoo-visitor, development, zoo

I've followed the documentation outlined here:

http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/templating/field.html

Where my custom field is `member_companyname` and is assigned as a matrix fieldtype.

```
{member_companyname sort="desc" limit="1"}
<input type="text" name="member_companyname" id="member_companyname" class="form-text" value="{member_companyname}" />

<input type="hidden" name="member_companyname[row_order][]" value="row_new_{count}">
<input type="hidden" name="member_companyname[row_new_{count}][col_id_20][]" value="[{entry_id}] [{url_title}] {title}">
{/member_companyname}
```

but it's not rendering it and spits it out as this:

`Company Name {member_companyname sort="desc" limit="1"} " />`

Comment: What about adding the orderby parameter?  Are there any variables between the tag pair that may be causing a conflict? Conditionals?  Can you post what you have between the matrix tags?

Comment: {member_companyname orderby="session_time" sort="desc"}
    {member_companyname}
{/member_companyname}     it just renders it just like that...  should i email you?  I feel that would be better, this  support system is confusing and wont' allow me to paste my code.

Comment: It might help to know that i'm using this inside {exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}

Comment: You could paste your code in a pastie http://pastie.org

Comment: Thank you for writing me back so fast!  I've also emailed you. http://pastie.org/8153638

Comment: Disregard.  I pretty much had to figure out my problem from another EE support site.  Do you guys have another documentation website?  I had no idea you had to wrap the zoo visitor tags inside channel entry tags if you're using matrix.   http://pastie.org/8154017   This is my code and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Matrix issue, but a Zoo Visitor template tag issue. Here's the winning code per comments posted above. I'm posting here for all to see.

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{zoo_visitor_id}" status="not closed" limit="1"}
  {exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
    Company Name: <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="member_companyname[row_order][]" value="row_new_0">
    <input type="text" name="member_companyname[row_new_0][col_id_1]" value="{member_companyname sort="desc" limit="1"}{member_companyname}{/member_companyname}"/>
  {/exp:zoo_visitor:update_form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```